# Relation between coefficient of determination, $R^2$, and significance in a regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, r-squared

I have performed a simple regression of the following form:

$y_t$ = $\beta_1x_{1,t}$ + $\beta_2x_{2,t}$ + $\beta_3x_{3,t}$

the $R^2$ turns out to be 38%.

$\hat\beta_1$ = 0.7 (significant at the 1%-level)

$\hat\beta_2$  = 2.3 (significant at the 1%-level)

$\hat\beta_3$  = 4.8 (not significant because of a high standard error)

In terms of interpretation, I understand what the $R^2$ and the coefficients $\hat\beta_1$ -$\hat\beta_3$ mean separately. But I don't understand how to interpret them together. Is the following wording correct:

The explanation power of the model (38%) stems mainly from $\hat\beta_1$ and $\hat\beta_2$. Or is there no relation between the significance of the coefficients and the $R^2$ in a regression?

Comment: The relationship between significance of the coefficients and that of the regression is complicated.  For examples, please explore some of the [related questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+significant+coefficient) that have been asked about this.  For instance, your regression could--in principle--still have $R^2=0.38$ after removing $x_2$ (and then $\beta_3$ might become highly significant).

Comment: @whuber I understand. Let's assume for simplicity the coefficient of $\beta_3$ is close to zero (and still not significant). Could you then imply that the explanatory power of the model stems from the other two coefficients?

Comment: No, because the size of $\beta_3$ could be anything depending on the units of measurement you use for expressing $x_3$ and those units are perfectly arbitrary, having no effect on the regression.

Comment: @whuber I see and I agree with you, however, again for simplification if we assumed that $x_1$ to $x_3$ are all the same unit (for example percent), would that change anything?

Comment: Good try, but still no: the explanatory power depends on the range of values attained by the variable.  *E.g.*, if the $x_i$ are all percents and if the $\hat\beta_i$ are all equal, then the independent variable with the largest standard deviation will usually be considered to have more "explanatory power." (In some cases the ranges of the $x_i$ might be more relevant than their SDs.)

Comment: @whuber alright thanks a lot for your input. I am still not 100% sure because I remember that I read the above formulation -- The explanation power of the model (x%) stems mainly from...-- in some kind of paper or scientific book.

Comment: Many sources are easily misunderstood and a few indeed are wrong. You need to read them carefully. For instance, there's quite a difference between the *standardized* coefficients ("betas") and the coefficients themselves; that difference accounts for most of our discussion. In other cases it is assumed or stipulated that the independent variables are *orthogonal,* which removes many of the complications of multiple regression (but holds only for certain kinds of designed experiments).